# How do i insert a row in to access using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am very new to c# and all I want to do to start off with in insert a row into an access database.

I am using Microsoft Visual C# express 2010, I have added a dataset an am unsure of where to go from here...

I have had a look on google etc.. and nothing worked for me :(

I have been trying with this code:

```
        DataRow newCustomersRow = timeDataSet.Tables["theTimes"].NewRow();
        newCustomersRow["ID"] = "1";
        newCustomersRow["User"] = "Test Name";
        newCustomersRow["LieuHours"] = "23";
        timeDataSet.Tables["theTimes"].Rows.Add(newCustomersRow);
```

There are only 3 colums in the table, it is for a bigger project that I am working on.

Please can some one help me?

Comment: How are <you establishing the connection with the MDB?

Comment: Can you explain what problem are you having?  Is there an error?  No inserted row?

Comment: I am useing conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
        @"Data source= C:\time.mdb";
 to connet to a MDB.

I am not getting an error or no inserted row. I am testing with viewing a field to a text box :(

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset add a tableadapter, there you can define your insert/delete/update/select methods through the wizard. It let's you inserted a row like this:

```
    using (timeDataSetTableAdapter ta = new timeDataSetTableAdapter())
{
    ta.Insert(1, "Test Name", "23");
}
```

It does the same as you were trying to do.

Also, read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171935%28VS.80%29.aspx